# Synchronize accelerometer and Gyroscope / Android

Tags: android

I am developing a mobile application under android and I need to retrieve the data from the accelerometer and gyroscope at exactly the same time ie I need to synchronize the two sensors to simultaneously read their values . I need to use a Service (not an Activity) but the value of the two event.timestamp are completely different.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {


    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        xa =event.values[0] ;
        ya =event.values[1] ;
        za =event.values[2] ;
        ta= event.timestamp;

    }

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
        xg = event.values[0];
        yg = event.values[1];
        zg = event.values[2];
        tg = event.timestamp;
   }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use 2 boolean flags, one for accelerometer and another for gyroscope, when both of them true it means you get at least one time from both of them, posibly one of them will have 3 or more times. Accelerometer sensor is quite fast. When both of them true set them to false again to get data from them again. You can't synchronize sensors with Sensor api.

```
boolean isAccelData = false;
boolean isGyroData = false;

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {


    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
        isAccelData = true;
    }
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        isGyroData = true;
    }
    if (isAccelData & isGyroData) {
        // DO something here
        isAccelData = false;
        isGyroData = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply. In the beginning I used the test if (ta == tg) {save the data in the database} but even after 5 minutes I find my table almost empty (sometimes I find 1 or 2 lines). If I can not use Sensor api for synchronization what tool would you advise.

Comment: It works just fine create a new project implement sensor listener and check how many accelerometer output you get for one gyroscope.

Use a log or System.println and set another one both has set their flags to true. This works. If you check compass applications you will see that it's used for setting rotation matrix after getting data from both accerlerometer and magnetic field sensor.

Comment: I see 3 or 4 accelerometer data then a magnetic field sensor data so it sets both flags and triggers action for it and set both flags to false again after action is executed.